# Change value on Json array and put in Hiddenfield

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have the next text in the hiddenfield in asp.net, this value is Json serialize

```
text = "[{ "Element":"E001", "City":"Madrid", "Country":"Spain"},
    { "Element":"E003", "City":"Paris", "Country":"Italy"},
    { "Element":"A001", "City":"Pekin", "Country":"China"}]
```

I want change the value of element whith a JS function like this

```
function ModificarDato(jsonelemento, jsonvalor)
{
    var vjson = eval($("[ id$='H_Ins").val());
    var vjson2 = `$`(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(vjson))).each(function ()
    {
        var vElemento = this.Element;
        var vCity = this.City;
        var vValor = this.Country;

        if (vElemento == jsonelemento)
        {
            this.Country = jsonvalor;
        }
    });

    var jsonvalorfinal = JSON.stringify(vjson2);

    alert("Valor final : " + jsonvalorfinal);
    $("[ id$='H_Ins").val(jsonvalorfinal);
}
```

The problem is that when i put the jsonvalorfinal in the hiddenfield the text is different

```
text = "{"0":{"Element":"E001", "City":"Madrid", "Country":"Spain"},
    "1":{"Element":"E003", "City":"Paris", "Country":"France"},
    "2":{"Element":"A003", "City":"Pekin", "Country":"China"},
    "length":3}
```

I need the same format of first string to continue whit another function. Its possible

Thanks

Comment: `I want change the value of element whith a JS function like this` i didnt understand that? Can you state clearly what is that you want to do?

Comment: There is a series of buttons that the user is pressing and each one executes the function ModificarDato("E003", "France");

Comment: So you want to update your JSON array? with the arguments of the function?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it as follows, you can find the index of the object you want to update and update its country property.**

```js
function ModifyData(element, newCountryValue) {
  let text = `[
    {
        "Element": "E001",
        "City": "Madrid",
        "Country": "Spain"
    },
    {
        "Element": "E003",
        "City": "Paris",
        "Country": "Italy"
    },
    {
        "Element": "A001",
        "City": "Pekin",
        "Country": "China"
    }
]`;

  let parsedArray = JSON.parse(text);

  let indexToBeModified = parsedArray.findIndex(item => item.Element == element);

  parsedArray[indexToBeModified].Country = newCountryValue;

  return parsedArray;

}

let modifiedArray = JSON.stringify(ModifyData("E001", "United States"), null, 4);

$("[ id$='H_Ins").val(modifiedArray);
```